# Convert Upstart config with dynamic instances to Systemd service

Tags: service, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, upstart, ubuntu-server

I have an Upstart service that can run multiple instances. Two dynamic parameters can be specified in any combination.

Is there a way to convert that into a systemd .service file?

```
start on (net-device-up and local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

instance $C,$B

exec [...] $C $B

respawn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

systemd supports templates which can be used to launch multiple instances of a service using a single template. From the docs in `man systemd.unit`:

> Optionally, units may be instantiated from a template file at runtie. This allows creation of
>        multiple units from a single configuration file. If systemd looks fora unit configuration file, it
>        will first search for the literal unit name in the file system. If tat yields no success and the unit     name contains an "@" character, systemd will look for a unittemplate that shares the same name but
>       with the instance string (i.e. the part between the "@" character an the suffix) removed. Example: if
>        a service getty@tty3.service is requested and no file by that names found, systemd will look for
>          getty@.service and instantiate a service from that configuratin file if it is found.
>
> To refer to the instance string from within the configuration file you may use the special "%i"    specifier in many of the configuration options.

In your case, starting a service for dynamic parameters "c" and "b" might look like:

```
 systemctl start myservice@b-c.service
```

Since systemd only supports one variable in the instance name, you may need to write wrapper shell script that unpacks an instance name of "b-c" to separate values of "b" and "c" to pass to your underlying service.